# Task based on Copy appears not to execute()

Tags: gradle

I have the following code in my build.gradle file:

```
task untarServer(type:Copy) {
    from tarTree('build/libs/server.tar.gz')
    into project.ext.tomcat + '../'
} << {
    println 'Unpacked, waiting for tomcat to deploy wars ...'
    sleep 10000
}

task deploy << {
    tarball.execute()
    untarServer.execute()
    stopTomcat.execute()
    startTomcat.execute()
}
```

Everything works great except untarServer, which appears not to run at all. Untar is based on an example from the [documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Script.html#tarTree%28java.lang.Object%29). Probably I've done something silly due to the late hour, but I'm missing it. How can I fix this? I have in the back of my mind that I could drop down to using ant.untar, but I'd like to do it the native gradle way if possible.

Edit: How do I know it's not running? because the println statement never shows up, the buld does not pause for 10 seconds, and the contents of the tarball do not show up in the "into" location.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the `} << {` syntax before; I'd change it to `doLast { ... }` inside the curly braces or `untarServer << {` (as a separate statement). Also, you should never call `execute()` on a task. It's totally unsupported and bad things will happen. Instead you should establish a task relationship (`dependsOn`, `mustRunAfter`, `finalizedBy`).

Comment: `<<` is a short cut for doLast (http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#N10222) I would love to not call execute, except it's the only way to actually make tasks happen in a unique order without changing their order for other operations. See discussion around http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-427, and the confusing and also re-use inhibiting `mustRunAfter` http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:ordering_tasks

Comment: I know what `<<` is. :-) Just saying that the way you apply it is unconventional (when I saw it, I wasn't even sure if it would work at all). I'm aware of the current limitations of task relationships, but it's nevertheless often possible to get around calling `execute()`. I'm pretty sure it's possible in this particular case. Anyway, even with your current code I'm fairly sure that `untarServer` will get executed (but not any dependencies it might have). You may be misinterpreting the effects that you are seeing.

Comment: It's definately not having the side effects desired. See my edit.

Comment: In that case, your best bet is to get rid of the `execute()`. I don't know any details about your build, but startTomcat-dependson-untarServer-dependsOn-tarball seems like a good start.